# Ganymed SSH2, creating file and writing file into a specific directory

Tags: java, file, netbeans, ssh

I recently started learning how to use ssh.
I am using Ganymed SSH2 to create a file in /bin and write words into it.
The name of the file is wrong (Test74024010477125945txt) -thejh helped me to fix this-, and nothing is written into it! -not fixed-

Code:

```
private void sshconnectActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String host = phoneip.getText();
    String username = "root";
    String password = passwd.getText();

    Connection conn = new Connection(host);
    try {
        conn.connect();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        progress.setText("Connection Failed");
    }
    // Done connection stuffs and instance
    try {
        boolean isAuthenticated = conn.authenticateWithPassword(username, password);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        progress.setText("Authentication failed");
    }

    try {
        Session sess = conn.openSession();
        sess.execCommand("cd /bin"); //useless i believe 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        progress.setText("Session failed");
    }

    try {
        SFTPv3Client client = new SFTPv3Client(conn);
        File tmpFile = new File("Test.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tmpFile);
        fw.write("this is a test");
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
        //temporary file 

        SFTPv3FileHandle handle = client.createFile("/bin/" + tmpFile.getName());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(tmpFile); 
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int i=0;
        long offset=0;

        while ((i = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) { //start writing to file
            client.write(handle,offset,buffer,0,i);
                           offset+= i;
        }
        //write file at /bin

        client.closeFile(handle);
        if (handle.isClosed())  progress.setText("Done!");;
            client.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Backup.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        progress.setText("SFTP failed"); //failure
    }

}
```

Any chances that i may have written wrongly?

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to read the documentation before using stuff, or at least when you notice that stuff doesn't work the way you want it to work. So, [let's have a look at the documentation of the method you're using:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)

> the name of the new file will be generated by concatenating the prefix, five or more internally-generated characters, and the suffix

The name of the generated file starts with "Test", a bunch of random characters follows, and it ends with "txt". What's wrong?

In case you want a file called `Test.txt`, do this:

```
File tmpFile = new File("Test.txt");
```

Creating the `FileWriter` instance should then create the file.

Comment: Ah thanks, I fixed one problem now. But i still left with writing the text into the file

Comment: @junyi00: Does it only not write into the file on the ssh server or does it not write into the local temporary file either?

Comment: The file doesn't seem to exist in the local file that the jar is contained

Comment: @junyi00: it should be created in the folder from which you're running the jarfile

Comment: It suddenly started working, but it doesn't seem to write anything into the file in the ssh server